# Technical solution to loss of index into powerpoint presention functionality

Tags: internet-explorer, url, powerpoint

Where I'm working we have a bunch of powerpoints that we'd like to put on the intranet. We'd also like to be able to open these presentations at any slide within the presentation. Got this to work by saving as .ppsx file, and adding '#' plus slide number to the url when linking from another MS office document (http://www.ellenfinkelstein.com/pptblog/hyperlink-to-a-specific-slide-in-another-presentation-or-specific-location-in-another-file/) but I can't get it to work in internet explorer 8 (old, I know. I've taken it up with my employers but there's nothing that can be done)

Anybody know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the same at my company. Linking from another MS office document works, but linking directly from the browser doesn't.

What I ended up doing making my user download the file to a standard download folder and then open the downloaded powerpoint on the slide. (this works, because you know the download folder)

EDIT: It is not such a nice solution, but I just created hyperlinks like:

```
H:/Downloads/test.pptx#3
```

Because our users leave most of the downloaded powerpoints in that folder anyway (and I have put a notification on the intranet that they should leave them there for linking to work).

Comment: You programmically opened the downloaded power point to the correct slide? Can you describe this in better detail?

Comment: These types of link (H:/Downloads/test.pptx#3) does not work for me with Office 2013. IE remove the part after # and Chrome does not find the file.